# Saving a form in microsoft access as pdf on one page

Tags: vba, database, forms, ms-access, pdf

in my Microsoft access database I have a form which I would like to save as pdf files.
I added a print button my form which uses a macro to let me print out or save my form as a pdf file, however the scaling is totally off and I end up having 2 pdf page and the right side of my form is below the left one...

When I manually change the print settings to a scale of 75%, the form perefctly fits into the pdf file however I have to manually do it every single time whenever I try to save my form as a pdf file...
I know that you can change the print settings in a report, however I can't use reports in my database.

Is there a way to change the scaling to 75% just by clicking the print button??

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I have been able to programmatically manipulate printer object to do things like select destination printer, duplexing, color mode, or designate source tray. No idea if can specify scaling for PrintToPDF. How exactly do you manually change the scale? I don't see that option with Access Print dialog when I select Microsoft PrintToPDF.

Comment: Consider building a report by copying all form controls to report based on same record source. Adjust controls to fit page length and orientation. Reports easily render to PDFs with appropriate scale.

Comment: Two things; maybe this is a printing problem consider invisible controls.  Make sure there are no invisible controls messing up the printing like textboxes or more likely layouts that are two wide or slightly go off the right side of the page.  Also try shrinking the printer margins.  Next are you printing rather than exporting.  If you are not exporting then try the exportwithformatting macro. or docmd.outputTo